# digikam: "Failed to load image"

Tags: digikam

How do I delete the images

[image: unlinked image icon]

in my album that give a "Failed to load image" error?

Whenever I try to send them to the trash, nothing happens.

Comment: What OS is it installed in?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's cross-posted https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/132043/digikam-failed-to-load-image

Comment: What OS? and what sort of images? I feel like there's more information needed for someone to be helpful. For example, what's so special about these images?

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike Linux. JPGs. The JPG files are corresponding to these "Failed to load image"s were deleted, but DigiKam doesn't delete the links to them.

Comment: FYI – the cross-post is closed at Photo-SE, so it's all SU's now. =)

Comment: Perhaps a disk issue? It sounds like a disk issue.

Comment: @music2myear Maybe. It's not full. I'm using BTRFS.

Comment: No, not full. It sounds as though there are bad sectors, or a failing disk. You should test the disk.